# Get java.security.PrivateKey from private key file generated by hyperledger ca

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, bouncycastle, ecdsa

Using [hyperledger-fabric-ca](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/) tool I got private key like following

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgrECQDuXL87QJKYDO
O/Z1TT+vzVPqF3106wT75dJF5OqhRANCAASsFuneE46/9JmUJCiQ14zWDKcFn6TL
kYl6mirTXefU7yYglu5hmehU0pD/PKKLkoTLNbPLn5RMdUe8aum3N1sZ
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

By default that software uses `ecdsa-with-SHA256` (`prime256v1`) Signature Algorithm

In my java application i need to have instance of java.security.PrivateKey that based on private key above.

I have tried following code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String privateKeyString = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
                "MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgrECQDuXL87QJKYDO\n" +
                "O/Z1TT+vzVPqF3106wT75dJF5OqhRANCAASsFuneE46/9JmUJCiQ14zWDKcFn6TL\n" +
                "kYl6mirTXefU7yYglu5hmehU0pD/PKKLkoTLNbPLn5RMdUe8aum3N1sZ\n" +
                "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";


        String privateKeyContent = privateKeyString.replaceAll("\\n|-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----|-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyContent.getBytes());
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
        PrivateKey privateKey = factory.generatePrivate(spec);
    }
```

but I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(ECKeyFactory.java:169)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:372)
    at QueryApp.main(QueryApp.java:36)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:330)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:356)
    at sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl.<init>(ECPrivateKeyImpl.java:73)
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyFactory.implGeneratePrivate(ECKeyFactory.java:237)
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(ECKeyFactory.java:165)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must base64-decode the contents, e.g.

```
String privateKeyContent = privateKeyString.replaceAll("\\n|-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----|-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyContent));
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
```